# How to see only one MMS if multiple MMS are in Farm

Tags: 2013, managed-metadata, farm

I have 3 Managed metadata service applications in the Farm with following names:

1. Managed metadata service
2. MMS1
3. MMS2

When i try to open MMS1 or MMS2, it always opened Managed metadata Service, why is that? I guess, i need to change somthing but i don't konw?

Comment: are you checking from Central admin?

Comment: Yes. Whenever i click MMS1 or MM2, it shows me always Managed metadata service, why is that?

Comment: on service application page, you click on the MMS1 and on next page it shows you Managed Metadata Service...right? Can you see the drop down on next page under Avaiable service applications? its great if you share the screen shot....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks Like you problem is MMS 1 and MMS2 are not associtated with Central Admin Web App.

- `Central admin > Application Management > Manage Web Applications >`
  click on Central Admin web app and from `Ribbon Click On Service
  Connections`.
- Please make Sure MMS1 and MMS2 are associated with Central admin as
  Managed Meta Data service is.